# Powershell Script works in PowerShell ISE but not Powershell

Tags: powershell-4.0

I copied a script that someone posted that activates changes to the Windows Cursor without restarting the computer. It works in Powershell ISE (Admin or not) but throws a "String Missing Terminator" error when run in Powershell.

Here is the script in its entirety:

```
Set-Itemproperty -path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors' -Name 'Arrow' -value 'C:\Windows\cursors\TKT_BLK.cur'

$CSharpSig = @'

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfo")]

public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
                 uint uiAction,
                 uint uiParam,
                 uint pvParam,
                 uint fWinIni);
‘@
$CursorRefresh = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $CSharpSig -Name WinAPICall -Namespace SystemParamInfo –PassThru
$CursorRefresh::SystemParametersInfo(0x0057,0,$null,0)
```

I am new to Powershell but I understand basic programming (to a degree). Powershell ISE must be doing something in the background that Powershell isn't. I just don't know what that is.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer to this and wanted to post it for others. Powershell V1.0 seems to have a bug - maybe, maybe not. What I found was that having a space in the path can cause powershell scripts to fail to execute when called from another script. They will work if loaded into powershell or powershell ISE and then run but the won’t work if called from another script OR started by double clicking on the script. I had two instances of this happening. One case the file name had a space in it and in the other the User path had a space in it.

I had a hard time finding out what was going on because the window would never stay open long enough to see the fault. I had to turn on logging for scripts to see it. The fault would be something like this:

(Error statement is NOT verbatim)

Could not find the requested file. Invalid path `C:\Users\FirstName…` where there was a space between first and last name.

Also, a path like `C:\This Is My File.ps1` would show an invalid path of `C:\This…`